# Relation between central force and potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, symmetry, potential-energy, conservative-field

I read this in one of the comments at this site 
"Any force that admit a potential is conservative"- what does it mean? Because I want to know why central force is related with potential as I have also encountered such context somewhere in my study about central force.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of "conservative force"?

Comment: Not clearly, but have studied that If work done by a force depends only on initial and final states and not on the path taken, it is called conservative force.

Comment: That's one of three mathematically equivalent definitions; "a force that can be expressed as the gradient of a potential" is another. Proving that these two are equivalent is a common exercise in introductory classical mechanics textbooks.

Comment: Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @Ashikakarikkalan It isn't reasonable to ask someone here to copy out a section of a textbook for you to read. This is standard theory that is covered in many textbooks and websites. You can find them with a very useful site called https://www.google.com

Comment: I think you have mistaken me. I'm not asking anyone to copy the text for me to read but just want to know others view over the same concept so that I can change my thinking and approach in a different way. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Look up Noether's theorem. It is the basis of every conservation law. It basically states that if a system can be translated in a way that for an observer makes no notable difference, there is a quantity related to it which is conserved

Comment: The OPs question seems to be more about the definition of a conservative force rather than conservation laws.

Comment: A conservative force is a subsection of conservation laws in general thus it is relevant in a broad p.o.v.

Comment: A conservative force is a definition, not a conservation law. I agree they are relevant to conservation laws, but this question is just about a definition.